Skipping analyzing "mediapipe": module is installed, but missing library stubs or py.typed marker
"Skipping analyzing "mediapipe": module is installed, but missing library stubs or py.typed marker"
I installed all the required libraries but the code did not work.
python verison 3.8.10
pip version 24.0
mediapipe 0.10.11
ı expecting mediapipe library works truely
